# How do I access this associative array in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a php file where I am pulling data from a database and I want to access its contents in javascript.  When I try to access the array with data[0].card_id I get "undefined".

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userId = 1;
  var updateUrl;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: {userId: userId},
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data[0].card_id);
      var suffix = ".html";
      fb.start('../Animations/' + updateUrl[0].card_id + suffix); 
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my php file

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

$user_id = $_POST['userId'];

$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";
}

$select = "SELECT card_id FROM decks WHERE id=$user_id ORDER BY order_num";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $select);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $animation[] = array(
        'card_id' => $row['card_id'],
    );
}

json_encode($animation);
echo $animation;
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

The array contains the following data

Array
(
   [0] => eating
   [1] => mummy

etc..
)

Comment: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) against.

Comment: Thanks i've read about sql injection and i'm going to sort this out as soon as my application is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

First: You aren't doing anything with the return value of `json_encode`.

Second: The PHP is claiming it is sending back HTML, so it wouldn't parsed as JSON anyway.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($animation);
```

Comment: Sorry, im quite new and I dont understand your answer, could you elaborate a bit more on header("Content-Type: application/json"); ? I understand the second part, i've made that mistake before silly me :(

Comment: When an HTTP server responds with a resource, it says what kind of resource it is. `application/json` means "a JSON text". `text/html` means "An HTML document". `image/png` means "A PNG formatted image". PHP will tell the server to send `text/html` unless you say otherwise. jQuery will look at the content-type and use that to decide what sort of parsing to do on the response before putting it into `data`.

Comment: Thanks, do I just put the header after the php tag like `<?php header("Content-Type: application/json");` ? Also, I tried returning `echo json_encode($animation);` but I still get undefined when I try to access the data using `alert(data[0].card_id);`

Comment: In practical terms, it doesn't matter where you set the header so long as it is before you give any output. For the sake of sanity, I'd put it between your business logic and your view logic (i.e. where I put in in the example in the answer).

Comment: Unless you have added the header, the data will be treated as HTML, so that result is to be expected. If you still have that problem after adding the header, `console.log(data)` to find out exactly what it is.

Comment: isnt console.log(data) the same as doing the alert but the output goes to the console instead?

Comment: @DavidFolksman — No. Since (a) I said to do it on `data` not `data[0].card_id` and (b) It won't stringify it first so you can examine the complete data structure.

Comment: Right, sorry.  So I did it on data and got eating,mummy,selectMummy,plate,selectPlate

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "url",
    data: {userId: userId},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[0].card_id);
        var suffix = ".html";
        fb.start('../Animations/' + updateUrl[0].card_id + suffix); 
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

There is no need to change MIME type, jQuery will handle this.

Comment: It makes much more sense to tell the server to say "This is JSON" instead of letting it lie and say "This is HTML" then it does to tell jQuery to ignore what the server claims.

Comment: I added the dataType but still get "undefined" in my alertbox :(

Comment: I wouldn't call hacking around a bad HTTP response "just fine". It's a substitute for doing it right.